# Problems with test class evaluating formulas and multiselect picklists

Tags: apex, unit-test

I cannot seem to get my test class to evaluate formulas very consistently (usually null) and it also seems that multiselect picklists are evaluated as null as well.  Does anyone have experience with this problem, or have ideas to code around it?  I should point out that this code works fine with real records and only seems to hiccup on the test records.

Any ideas?

Here is part of the code where I am pushing in values to the multiselect picklist:

```
        // Inventory Location 1
        SVMXC__Site__c inv = new SVMXC__Site__c();
        inv.SVMXC__Stocking_Location__c = true;
        inv.BSP_SAP_Location__c = 'V11111';
        inv.BSP_Consignable_Models__c = 'BLACK_WHITE, BLACK_WHITE_CTMC, BLACK_WHITE_CTS, MCD_SURETAMP_1STEP, NESPRESSO, SURE_TAMP_AUTO, SURE_TAMP_STEAM';
        inv.Name = 'Troys Stocking Loc';
        inv.NTT_Metro_Remote__c = 'METRO';
        insert inv;
```

Here is a screenshot of what the coverage is showing in the Developer Console:

[image]

This is the original code, where I had been using formulas, which test classes don't seem to work very well.  I expected from past experience that I could reference the field directly, but since it returns null, I wonder if there is something with multiselect picklists that test classes argue with.  Again, this works fine with real data.

```
            // check to see what consignment model parts are stocked at the servicer's stocking location... 

            if (workDetail.BSP_Consignment_Models_at_SLOC__c != null) 
            {
               if( workDetail.BSP_Consignment_Models_at_SLOC__c.contains( 'THERMOPLAN' ) )
                    cStockToQuery.add('THERMOPLAN');
                if( workDetail.BSP_Consignment_Models_at_SLOC__c.contains( 'SURE_TAMP_STEAM' ) )
                    cStockToQuery.add('SURE_TAMP_STEAM');
                if( workDetail.BSP_Consignment_Models_at_SLOC__c.contains( 'SURE_TAMP_AUTO' ) )
                    cStockToQuery.add('SURE_TAMP_AUTO');
                if( workDetail.BSP_Consignment_Models_at_SLOC__c.contains( 'MCD_SURETAMP_1STEP' ) )
                    cStockToQuery.add('MCD_SURETAMP_1STEP');
                if( workDetail.BSP_Consignment_Models_at_SLOC__c.contains( 'NESPRESSO' ) )
                    cStockToQuery.add('NESPRESSO');
                if( workDetail.BSP_Consignment_Models_at_SLOC__c.contains( 'BLACK_WHITE_CTS' ) )
                    cStockToQuery.add('BLACK_WHITE_CTS');
                if( workDetail.BSP_Consignment_Models_at_SLOC__c.contains( 'BLACK_WHITE' ) )
                    cStockToQuery.add('BLACK_WHITE');
                if( workDetail.BSP_Consignment_Models_at_SLOC__c.contains( 'BLACK_WHITE_CTMC' ) )
                    cStockToQuery.add('BLACK_WHITE_CTMC');
                if( workDetail.BSP_Consignment_Models_at_SLOC__c.contains( 'BUNN_FSE' ) )
                    cStockToQuery.add('BUNN_FSE');
```

Here is where I am populating the work order, back through the technician and inventory location, where ultimately the multipicklist is populated.

```
    // Work Order 2                     
    SVMXC__Service_Order__c wo2 = new SVMXC__Service_Order__c();
    wo2.recordtypeid = WOrtMapByName.get('Parent').getRecordTypeId(); 
    wo2.SVMXC__Company__c = acc.id;
    wo2.NTT_Claim_Status__c = 'Incomplete';
    wo2.SVMXC__Order_Status__c = 'Resolved';
    wo2.NTT_Admin_Line_Created__c = true;
    wo2.SVMXC__Order_Type__c = 'Service';
    wo2.SVMXC__Component__c = ip.id;
    wo2.SVMXC__Product__c = prod.Id; 
    wo2.BSP_Vendor_Rate_Code__c = 'MAST_50K';
    wo2.SVMXC__Group_Member__c = tech.Id;
    insert wo2;

    // SP Technician
    SVMXC__Service_Group_Members__c tech = new SVMXC__Service_Group_Members__c();       
    tech.Name = 'Troy Smith';      
    tech.NTT_Account__c = vendor.Id;
    tech.SVMXC__Active__c = true;
    tech.SVMXC__Break_Type__c = 'Fixed';
    tech.NTT_CBSA__c = '12345';
    tech.SVMXC__City__c = 'Argenta';
    tech.BSP_Claims_Active__c = true;
    tech.BSP_Cost_Center__c = 'FSE08';
    tech.SVMXC__Country__c = 'United States';
    tech.SVMXC__Email__c = 'troy.smith@bunn.com';
    tech.SVMXC__Enable_Scheduling__c = true;
    tech.SVMXC__Inventory_Location__c = inv.Id;
    tech.SVMXC__Phone__c = '217-454-1234';
    tech.NTT_Product_Line_Serviced__c = 'BLACK_WHITE; BLACK_WHITE_CTMC; BLACK_WHITE_CTS; MCD_SURETAMP_1STEP; NESPRESSO; SURE_TAMP_AUTO; SURE_TAMP_STEAM';
    tech.NTT_Servicer_Type__c = 'RST';
    tech.SVMXC__Service_Group__c = team.Id;    
    tech.SVMXC__State__c = 'IL';
    tech.NTT_State__c = 'IL';
    tech.SVMXC__Street__c = '123 Main St.';
    tech.Technician_Time_Zone__c = 'America/Chicago';
    tech.SVMXC__Third_Party__c = true;
    tech.BSP_WorkOrder_Distribution_List__c = 'Test';
    tech.SVMXC__Zip__c = '62501';
    insert tech;

    // Inventory Location 1
    SVMXC__Site__c inv = new SVMXC__Site__c();
    inv.SVMXC__Stocking_Location__c = true;
    inv.BSP_SAP_Location__c = 'V11111';
    inv.BSP_Consignable_Models__c = 'BLACK_WHITE, BLACK_WHITE_CTMC, BLACK_WHITE_CTS, MCD_SURETAMP_1STEP, NESPRESSO, SURE_TAMP_AUTO, SURE_TAMP_STEAM';
    inv.Name = 'Troys Stocking Loc';
    inv.NTT_Metro_Remote__c = 'METRO';
    insert inv;
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. -- Troy

Comment: Here is the original code that uses a formula, and formulas seem to be problematic in test classes, so I thought I could work around it by calling the field directly.  Unfortunately, that has not been fruitful.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that in your test the `SVMXC__Site__c` instance that your code references always has `BSP_Consignable_Models__c` `null`. Are you sure the code you are testing is querying the right instance? Are you taking the ID of `inv` and inserting or updating the right `SVMXC__Inventory_Location__c` object and so on up the relationship chain?

Incidentally if you used a local variable:

```
String models = workDetail.SVMX__Service_Order__r ... BSP_Consignable_Models__c;
```

your chain of ifs would be easier to understand (and execute a bit quicker):

```
if (model.contains('THERMOPLAN;')) cStockToQuery.add('THERMOPLAN');
else if ...
```

On formula fields, note that there is now an SObject [recalculateFormulas](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_recalculateFormulas) method that:

> Recalculates all formula fields on an sObject, and sets updated field
>   values. Rather than inserting or updating objects each time you want
>   to test changes to your formula logic, call this method and inspect
>   your new field values. Then make further logic changes as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the recalculateFormulas method, I will certainly look at that, and thanks for the string idea - I agree and will try to implement that as well.  As for your first point about the site instance, I have edited my post to show how I am populating and referencing the data.

Comment: I added the line:  workDetail.recalculateFormulas(); and received this error:   17:10:17.162 (10913400158)|FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, ServiceOrderLineTriggers: execution of BeforeInsert

caused by: System.UnexpectedException: Unable to create/update fields: IsDeleted. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.